# Convert json single-item arrays to objects using bash/jq

Tags: arrays, json, jq, flatten

Given the example JSON below:

```
{
  "account_number": [
    "123456"
  ],
  "account_name": [
    "name"
  ],
  "account_id": [
    654321
  ],
  "username": [
    "demo"
  ]
}
```

I'd like to get:

```
{
  "account_number": "123456",
  "account_name": "name",
  "account_id": 654321,
  "username": "demo"
}
```

Currently, I'm brute forcing it with `| sed 's/\[//g' | sed 's/\]//g' | jq '.'` ... but of course, that's ugly and causes issues if any of the values contain `[` or `]`.

I've been unsuccessful with `jq`'s `flatten` and other loops and mapping techniques like `| jq -s '{Item:.[]} | .Item |add'` to try and flatten the single-item arrays. Ideally, it would work where it would flatten arrays `[...]` to flat elements/objects `{...}`. Either way something better than replacing all occurrences of square brackets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short and sweet:

```
 map_values(first)
```

Comment: Love the most elegant, thanks for sharing.

Comment: Almost 50% shorter, yet nowhere near that elegance: `.[]|=.[0]` ☺

Comment: If elegance is in the eye of the beholder, shortness must be in the eye of the metric.

Answer (score 1):

Use `with_entries`, changing each value to the first element of itself:

```
jq 'with_entries(.value |= .[0])' file.json
```

Comment: Super, that makes sense, I didn't even realize that. Live and learn, thank you!